# Asisgn LPCWSTR array from std::wstring

Tags: c++, arrays, std, wstring, lpcwstr

I am creating a dynamic array of LPCWSTR, and want to assign values at run time.
I have following code :

```
cin>>count
LPCWSTR * lpwcstrArray = new LPCWSTR[count]();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // some logic to create different wstring on each iteration
    wstring tempWString = L"somerandomstuff";

    lpwcstrArray[i] = reinterpret_cast<LPSWSTR>tempWString.c_str();
}
```

Now if i access lpwcstrArray - all the indexs point at data of last string that was assigned.

I know this is not correct way to assign values, but i do not know the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing pointers that point at the internals of *temporary* `std::wstring` objects.  When those objects are destroyed on each loop iteration, your array is left with danging pointers.  You need to dynamically allocate the individual strings instead, eg:

```
std::cin >> count
LPWSTR *lpwstrArray = new LPWSTR[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // some logic to create different wstring on each iteration
    std::wstring tempWString = L"somerandomstuff";

    LPWSTR str = new WCHAR[tempWString.length()+1];
    const wchar_t *p = tempWString.c_str();
    std::copy(p, p+tempWString.length(), str);

    lpwstrArray[i] = str;
}

// use lpwstrArray as needed...

// don't forget to free the memory when you are done using it...
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    delete[] lpwstrArray[i];
delete[] lpwstrArray;
```

Depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, something more like the following would be safer, at least if you just need read-only access to the strings (which you likely do, as the `C` in `LPCWSTR` stands for `const`, so the user of the array is not going to be modifying them):

```
std::cin >> count

std::vector<std::wstring> wstrArray(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // some logic to create different wstring on each iteration
    wstrArray[i] = L"somerandomstuff";
}

std::vector<LPWSTR> lpwstrArray(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    lpwstrArray[i] = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wstrArray[i].c_str());

// use lpwstrArray as needed. if you need to pass it where an
// LPWSTR* is expected, you can use &lpwstrArray[0] for that...

// lpwstrArray and wstrArray will be freed automatically
// when they go out of scope...
```

Comment: Thanks, i did the second part yesterday and it was working. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Accomplishing this using the first loop, to create std::wstring and assign it to LPCWSTR.

Answer (score 3):

`wstring tempWString` is created and destroyed with each iteration of the loop.
You have dangling pointers in your `lpwcstrArray` and are experiencing undefined behaviour when you access one of them.
You need to allocate the space yourself or use a `std::wstring` as the array type instead of a `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, As I have to use LPCWSTR* , what is the right api to allocate memory here, i am new to c++

Comment: You would use `new`. You can google it, and don't forget that you have to free the resources that you allocate using `delete`.

Comment: Thanks,Created an array instead to store wstring and then assign so that pointers point to valid memory.

Comment: Accepting Remy's answer, as it gives the solution. Unluckily we cannot accept more than 1.

Answer (score -1):

Try the approach

```
    std::wstring ws(_T("Hello"));
    LPCTSTR lps= (LPCTSTR)(ws.c_str());

    TRACE(lps);
```

Notes:

- You should not use the W types directly (ex: `LPCWSTR`). Use the T types instead (ex: `LPCTSTR`). Why? Because they will automatically translate to the version they should be (`LPCSTR` for non-Unicode / ASCII; `LPCWSTR` for Unicode), depending on your project.
- For the same reason you should surround your strings with `_T()` or precede them with an `L`.
- Try to dive deep using "Go To Definition" successively beginning on LPCTSTR
- See also the _tcscpy_s function documentation

Comment: Your advice is backwards. You should *avoid* using the TCHAR-based APIs and use the Unicode APIs instead. Windows has been Unicode-based for almost 2 decades now. The TCHAR APIs are for legacy support for apps that have to support Windows 9x/ME. Also, `_T()` (and `TEXT()`) is not the same thing as `L"..."`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am with the tchar.h file at hands. I see #define _T(x)       __T(x) and #define __T(x)      L ## x
Explain me please what is different in terms of practical effect. Trying to Go To Definition of L always takes me to elsewhere, not the definition of this L.

Comment: There is no definition of `L`, it is built in to the compiler itself as part of the C/C++ language. `_T()` and `L` "do the exact same thing" only when `_UNICODE` is defined, where `_T("x")` maps to `L"x"`. When `_UNICODE` is not defined, `_T("x")` maps to `"x"` instead. Passing L"x" directly to a `_TCHAR`-based API is wrong, you have to pass `_T("x")` instead so it maps correctly in both environments. That is what you need when you have to cross-compile a single codebase for both Ansi (Win9x/ME) and Unicode (NT4+) versions of Windows...

Comment: ...  It is pretty rare to actually need to do that nowadays, though. Especially when writing new code. Everything is Unicode now, and there is a performance hit whenever you call the older Ansi-based APIs, so they (and `TCHAR` itself) should be avoided whenever possible/feasible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I removed the "Both options do the exact same thing" statement as a result of your observation.